# Refreshing IDockableWindow with DGV using C#

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, visual-studio

I am having a IDockableWindow which will display a row of data which is a DATATABLE on DGV.
below is my code.

**Page1.cs:**

```
 private void toolStripMenuItem_Open_detail_page_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UID dockWinID = new UIDClass();
        dockWinID.Value = ThisAddIn.IDs.DetailsPage;

        IDockableWindow dockWindow = ArcMap.DockableWindowManager.GetDockableWindow(dockWinID);
        dockWindow.Show(true);


        DNRToolBar.WaterRightsDetailsPage WRDetailsPage = new DetailsPage(this.Hook);
        WRDetailsPage.WRDetailsPageLOAD(3);//passing in an integer directly for test.
    }
```

**Page2.cs:** - this is the default page which the arcGIS template creates once you choose to create a dock able window and below is my method in it

```
  public void WRDetailsPageLOAD(int ID)
    {
        WaterRightsInfoDBAccess dbAccess = new WaterRightsInfoDBAccess();
        DGV_WaterRightsDetailsPage.DataSource = dbAccess.WRDetailsPageData(ID);
    }
```

Once the Dockable window is shown with the DataTable when I try to call the click event again it does execute the WRDetailsPageLOAD(int ID) but the DGV in the dockwindow does not refresh.

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=110408 this is exactly the same issue but I dint find it helpful

Comment: What is DGV?  I think all but the most common abbreviations should be spelled out the first time that they are asked in a question.